# Account vs Wallet

Tags: mist, wallets, accounts

I think the difference between two is that wallets are a bit more feature-rich like seeing the previous transactons.

but my "Main account" is somehow special, it is not a wallet because it is missing this "show interface" button but I can still see the previous transactions.

so is main account an exception that's a mix of an account and a wallet?

Or am I missing something?

I am talking about Mist interface.

Comment: Wow marked as duplicate.. There are more people willing to hunt duplicates than to people who want to help like StackOverflow, I know what is written there but I smell an exceptional case with the "main account".
Maybe reading a couple of sentences was too much to ask, as the title clearly hints a duplicate..